# Jmeter recorded script is not doing functionality

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have recorded a script to create user on an app,when i playback it runs successfully and in test result tree it gives me that it is passed without any error ,but when i go in the system manually to see if user is created or not ,it wont show me that user is created.
is there anything else i need to add to my script to make my script do the desired functionality .

Comment: Why don't you show us your script?

Comment: Sometimes the response code is 200 but in result tree you have 2 child for a node, showing that there's some error. Are you using any value in the response of a request in any other requests? would you please show us the scrips and result tree

Answer (score 2):

1. When you record script and replay it, all the session-ids or dynamic values are going to turn stale after some time. In this case you need to extract these id's from request and pass it ahead.
2. You need to understand your requests and parameters being sent, before you run the tests. So compare the recorded requests with actual request being made from browser. This way you know what all parameters are dynamic. Once you figure out dynamic parameters use 'Regular Expression Extractor' post-processor to extract these values and pass them in further requests.
3. Add response assertions to check the correctness so even if you get 200 ok response assertion will validate the correctness of response and will not mislead you.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter's proxy records HTTP Requests as they are, in absolute majority of cases some extra work is required in order to make them behave as expected.

1. Make sure you add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test plan
2. Check if there are any dynamic request parameters. For instance record your test scenario 2 times and compare recorded scripts. If you see a request parameter with the same name but having different value - it is the case and you will need to handle it. The process is called "correlation" and JMeter provides the following test elements:

   - [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) - for text
   - [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) - for HTML
   - [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)  - for XHTML, XML and HTML

   See [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) article for example of implementing correlation in JMeter test.
3. You can use [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination to check request and response details as well as JMeter Variables and Properties values.